# Compute grads of cloned tensor Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, tensor

I am having a hard time with gradient computation using PyTorch.

I have the outputs and the hidden states of the last time step `T` of an RNN.

I would like to clone my hidden states and compute its grad after backpropagation but it doesn't work.

After reading [pytorch how to compute grad after clone a tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52926847/pytorch-how-to-compute-grad-after-clone-a-tensor), I used  `retain_grad()` without any success.

Here's my code

```
        hidden_copy = hidden.clone()
        hidden.retain_grad()
        hidden_copy.retain_grad()
        outputs_T = outputs[T]
        targets_T = targets[T]
        loss_T = loss(outputs_T,targets_T)
        loss_T.backward()
        print(hidden.grad)
        print(hidden_copy.grad)
```

`hidden_grad` gives an array while `hidden_copy.grad` gives `None`.

Why does `hidden_copy.grad` give `None` ? Is there any way to compute the gradients of a cloned tensor ?

Comment: Is `hidden_copy` used to compute `outputs_T`? If not then it makes sense that it wouldn't get a gradient since `loss_T` doesn't depend on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, hidden_copy isn't used to compute outputs_T put hidden is. As hidden_copy is a copy of hidden (which is used to compute outputs_T), wouldn't it make sense that its gradients isn't None ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments the problem is that `hidden_copy` is never visited during the backward pass.

When you perform backward pytorch follows the computation graph backwards starting at `loss_T` and works backwards to all the leaf nodes. It only visits the tensors which were used to compute `loss_T`. If a tensor isn't part of that backward path then it won't be visited and it's `grad` member will not be updated. Basically by creating a copy of the tensor and then not using it to compute `loss_T` this results in a "dead-end" in the computation graph.

To illustrate take a look at this diagram representing a simplified view of a computation graph. Each node in the graph is a tensor where the edges point back to direct descendants.

[image]

Notice if we follow the path back from `loss_T` to the leaves then we never visit `hidden_conv`. Note that a leaf is a tensor with no descendants and in this case `input` is the only leaf.

This is an extremely simplified computation graph used to demonstrate a point. Of course in reality there are probably many more nodes between `input` and `hidden` and between `hidden` and `output_T` as well as other leaf tensors since the weights of layers are almost certainly leaves.

Comment: Thank your for your explanation. I wanted to copy the hidden states of my RNN into a list and get the gradients of the loss wrt to each hidden states. 

Doesn't it mean I cannot get the gradient of the loss wrt to the hidden state at a timestep t, as the hidden states cannot be cloned and remain in the computation graph ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using inplace operations on the hidden states. For example if you use `hidden_1 = hidden` then reassign `hidden` to something new `hidden_1` still points to the original tensor of `hidden` while `hidden` now references a different tensor. Basically try removing the `.clone()` and see how that works.